# similar to jquery unbind, how to cancel the event.preventDefault() from eventlistner to make checkbox checked properly

Tags: event-handling, unbind

I have a checkbox blocked by event.preventDefault() from some external js, and without jquery, do we have similar way to unbind the click event to make checkbox works fine?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iannievan/hx4rqcyn/4/)

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="a">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c" onclick='console.log(this.checked)'>
</div>
```

```
  window.addEventListener("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

I have alphinjs instead of jquery and do not want use jquery, any idea